# connect-mongo sessions collection is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

Im using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/) module for mongo session store

```
var express  = require('express');
var http  = require('http');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

mongoose.connect(db);

mongoose.connection.on('open',function(db){
    console.log('connected ??')
})

var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
```

....

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({
    secret : 's3cr3t',
    store  : new MongoStore({
        mongoose_connection : mongoose.connection
    }),
    cookie : {
        maxAge : 60000 // 60k msconds
    }
})
```

I can see `connected?` logged . but when i open mongo try db.sesssions.find() it reutns nothing . I gave requests with incognito , ie ,cleared cookies  but the db is just empty but the test db and sessions collection are created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `express.session` instead of `express.cookieSession`:

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret : 's3cr3t',
    store  : new MongoStore({
        mongoose_connection : mongoose.connection
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes . Thanks . I solved this issue while ago but forget to update the answer